# Nginx: configure streams for docker containers with hostname

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, hostname

I have a few Docker containers:

- Nginx
- frontend
- api
- etc.

I'm trying to configure Nginx to make it possible to send requests using hostname.

My Nginx configuration looks like this:

```
upstream app {
    server frontend:3000;
}

server {
    server_name `my_hostname`;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # Define the maximum file size on file uploads
        client_max_body_size 5M;
    }
    location /api {
        rewrite "^/api/(.*)$" /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://api:9002;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    }
}
```

So, this app is deployed to AWS. I've changed the hostname of my EC2 instance to `my_hostname`.

All requests via IP works fine, but I can't request using `my_hostname`. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: My_hostname is just for example? If not, it can't work as the domain name my_hostname is not public. It will work only if you edit your host file to bind the public IP of your Amazon server with my_hostname

Comment: @FiberOptic, yes, it's just for example. I've added `127.0.0.1 my_real_hostname`, set `sudo hostname my_real_hostname` and restarted an EC2 instance. It has an expected hostname.